# Linking to product page gives "Not Available for bots to index" error on screen instead of the old style App Details

Tags: windows-store

> https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/name/ID

Linking to my app product page gives "Not Available for bots to index"

What is the proper syntax to place a href link to the product so that users online can view it as html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a final solution, just a workaround.

We've been seeing the same issue with our own app for the past few days and we've started seeing reports of people encountering this with all kinds of apps, including even Microsoft's own AppInstaller. It seems to be a server-side rate-limiting/caching issue at Microsoft as changing anything in the URL fixes the problem temporarily -- only to get back to the same issue a few hours later. We also found that VPN-ing to some locations (mostly to the US) helped as well, and this throttling seems to be specific to an app & an availability region (when it got blocked, it blocked across all Europe, but not in US for example). It seems to come & go as we have not seen a big drop in new install counts.

As a temporary solution we ended up adding a random string to the end of the URL. We used GCLID as we found it to be the least offensive way -- it could just as well be a legitimate tracking ID we pass over. So now the URL we link to looks like this:

```
https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/[APPNAME]/[APPID]?gclid=f-3579a28842a7bcac7ba630d698829e9b
```

Where the "f-xxxx" value is generated using the md5() of the timestamp -- but it could be any ever-changing value, even a random number.

We've reached out to our MS contact about this but we haven't heard back yet.

Comment: Microsoft said that they've rolled out a fix, so this workaround might not be necessary anymore. You can see that it likely worked due to the drop in [Google queries](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=now%207-d&q=%22not%20available%20for%20bots%20to%20index%22) for this.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue half an hour ago, but it seems recovered now.

If you own an app, you can confirm Product identity in Partner Center:

> You can share the direct link and Store ID to help customers find your app in the Store:
>
> - URL: https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/*12CharsAppId*
> - Store ID: *12CharsAppId*
> - Store protocol link: ms-windows-store://pdp/?productid=*12CharsAppId*

The above address would be recommended but the `apps.microsoft.com` URL should also work.

Answer (score 0):

I work on apps.microsoft.com. I can confirm that there was an issue on our end that appeared on August 23. This issue has been resolved.

And the proper link, of course, is this:

- [https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/[your](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/%5Byour) product id here]

Comment: Thanks but the link syntax you gave does not seem to work..  at least for my native app, it seems to require a syntax /detail/productname/id and a few language parameters, too...

Comment: Product name is optional. Give me your product ID and I can check it out.

Comment: Also, language is optional. If omitted, we display in the browser's language.

Comment: Thanks, just figured it out: the shorter link does not work if the App is not available in US region. My app is available in all regions outside US.  I would like to use another PACKAGE for USA due branding, do you know if it is possible?

Comment: There seem to be another bug with STORE; its not possible to link to products or pages,
perhaps you can look for this one; e.g. url https://apps.microsoft.com/store/collections/BestProductivityApps  gives  
Refused to execute script from 'https://apps.microsoft.com/store/js/build-8a6b0dc38d94b9c432a8.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: Browser caching issue. (Hard refresh and you'll see it work.) We're rolling out a fix so browsers don't serve stale HTML pages, which will fix this issue.